# Writing a RSA public key in a text file

Tags: java, encryption, fileoutputstream

I am trying to generate a RSA key pair and store RSA public key in a text file so I can open it later. I have my text file but after I run my saveRSApublicKey function, it does not write anything to my pubkey.txt file. Please help.

```
public class Server {

static KeyPair keys;
static byte[] RSAencrypted;
File file;
FileOutputStream fop = null;

public Receiver() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException{
    keys = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair();
}


public void saveRSApublicKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException{
    byte[] pubKeyBytes = keys.getPublic().getEncoded();
    file = new File("pubkey.txt");
    fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fop.write(publicKeyBytes);
    fop.close();

}
```

}

Comment: Yes. Sorry I meant "after i run my method" I edited.

Comment: why is `keys` static?

Comment: Does `pubKeyBytes` contain bytes?

Comment: yes it does contain bytes.

Comment: I do not understand why it does not write anything to the text file

Comment: maybe you are looking at the wrong file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129306/discussion-between-mint-k-and-scary-wombat).

Comment: You are getting the public key content in `pubKeyBytes`, but writing streams from `publicKeyBytes`. 
`publicKeyBytes` is not even initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Notice `pubKeyBytes` and `publicKeyBytes` are not same.

You are getting the public key content in `pubKeyBytes`, but writing streams from `publicKeyBytes`. It should be:

```
byte[] pubKeyBytes = keys.getPublic().getEncoded();
file = new File("pubkey.txt");
fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
fop.write( pubKeyBytes );
fop.close();
```

How did your code compiled anyway?